# Aplicativo Android não acessa API no SDK mais recente(28) - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sdk

Bom dia, desenvolvi uma app utilizando android studio que não acessa web service em uma versão do SDK do android, mais especificamente o SDK 28. Eu já declarei no android manifest o target SDK:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="28"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

e também no Gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.companyname.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1.0
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

alguém sabe como resolver esse problema? já busquei informação diretamente na documentação oficial (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28?hl=pt-BR), mas não encontrei nada para resolver o problema. Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Obs: a classe que uso para consumo do web service é HttpURLConnection.

Comment: o seu link é em http ou https?

Comment: Opa @MurilloComino, obrigado por responder, os links que uso são HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta fazer o seguinte, dentro do seu Manifest em application acrescente:

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Isso permite todas as solicitações de HTTP

Comment: olha muito obrigado, resolveu o problema.